# How can I find which dependency dragged in OkHttp?

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

android-gradle defines the task `dependencies` which lists the dependency hierarcy for any Android project. Yet it seems not to be complete. While the text output below is the output from a `dependencies` run of my project, the screenshot further down shows that `OkHttp` is a dependency not listed. How come? Why doesn't `dependencies` list it and how do I find out which library pulled it in?

```
_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-api:0.8.1
+--- project :mylib-common
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
|    +--- com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
|    |    \--- com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.1.6
|    +--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.at:atinternet:1.6
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16
|    +--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    |    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13 -> 1.0.16
|    +--- com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3
|    |    \--- org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.1
|    +--- de.spring.mobile:spring-appsensor-android:1.7.1
|    |    \--- de.spring.util.android:spring-util-android:1.7.1
|    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    +--- com.katalysator:glimr:1.8.1
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2
|         +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.2
|         |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.6
|         +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.6
|         +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.5
|         |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.2 (*)
|         |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.6
|         \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.3
+--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2 (*)
+--- com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:1.0.3
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0
+--- me.tatarka:bindingcollectionadapter:0.16
|    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc3 -> 1.0-rc5
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc5 -> 1.1
|    +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc5 -> 1.1
|    +--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.0-rc3 -> 1.0-rc5
|    |    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc5 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc5 -> 1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
+--- me.tatarka:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:0.16
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3 -> 23.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc3 -> 1.0-rc5 (*)
|    +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.0-rc5 -> 1.1
|    +--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.0-rc3 -> 1.0-rc5 (*)
|    \--- me.tatarka:bindingcollectionadapter:0.16 (*)
+--- com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4
+--- com.android.databinding:library:1.0-rc5 (*)
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.1
+--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.0-rc5 (*)
+--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.6
+--- com.fernandocejas.frodo:frodo-runtime:0.8.1
\--- com.android.databinding:compiler:1.1
     +--- com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:1.1
     |    +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.1
     |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
     |    +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4:4.5
     |    |    +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-runtime:4.5
     |    |    |    +--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
     |    |    |    \--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-annotations:4.5
     |    |    +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4-annotations:4.5
     |    |    +--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
     |    |    \--- org.antlr:ST4:4.0.8
     |    |         \--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
     |    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
     |    \--- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3
     +--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:1.1
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0-beta-1103
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-runtime:1.0.0-beta-1103
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
     +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
     +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
     +--- com.tunnelvisionlabs:antlr4:4.5 (*)
     \--- com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3
```

**Screenshot runtime of threads**

[image: Thread list from debugger showing evidence of OkHttp]

Comment: Check it out in android dependencies list, the option is there in project structure.

Comment: OkHttp isn't listed there: http://i.imgur.com/fpC7qT4.png . And besides, it wouldn't tell me _why_ it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the android sdk,...

> Yep. OkHttp became the engine that powers HttpUrlConnection as of Android 4.4.

SOURCE - https://twitter.com/jakewharton/status/482563299511250944
(from our favorite Jake)